# How to show $\mathbb R^n-\mathbb R^m$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb R^{n-m}-\{0\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to show $\mathbb R^n-\mathbb R^m$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb R^{n-m}-\{0\}$? Can I find some homotopy map to prove this? I can imagine the picture, how can I find a real homotopy?

Comment: As stated, this is untrue. $R^{n-m}$ is homotopy equivalent to a point, while $R^n-R^m$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-m-1}$.

Comment: $R^n - R^m$ is homotopy equivalent to a $S^{n - m - 1}$.

Comment: @Alex this is true, gave that statement to little thought. It has been corrected.

Comment: @Chanler Sorry about that, the origin should be deleted, I forget to type......So how should I prove this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb R^n - \mathbb R^m$ is really $(\mathbb R^{n-m}-\{0\}) \times \mathbb R^m$. Try to find a homeomorphism between them.